# How to extract data from a line which has fields separated by '|' character in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, file-handling

I have data in the following format in a text file. **Filename - empdata.txt**
Note that there are no blank space between the lines.

> Sl|EmployeeID|Name|Department|Band|Location
>
> 1|327427|Brock Mcneil|Research and Development|U2|Pune
>
> 2|310456|Acton Golden|Advertising|P3|Hyderabad
>
> 3|305540|Hollee Camacho|Payroll|U3|Bangalore
>
> 4|218801|Simone Myers|Public Relations|U3|Pune
>
> 5|144051|Eaton Benson|Advertising|P1|Chennai

I have a class like this

```
class empdata
{
public:
int sl,empNO;
char name[20],department[20],band[3],location[20];
};
```

I created an array of objects of class empdata.
How to read the data from the file which has n lines of data in the above specified format and store them to the array of (class)objects created?

This is my code

```
int main () {
string line;
ifstream myfile ("empdata.txt");
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) //processing only first 10 lines of the file
{
    getline (myfile,line);
    //What should I do with this "line" so that I can extract data 
    //from this line and store it in the class object?             
     
}

  return 0;
}
```

**So basically my question is how to extract data from a string which has data separated by '|' character and store each data to a separate variable**

Comment: what have you try so far ,

Comment: I need an idea on how to proceed.
Have been trying to figure out for hours. Please help

Comment: I have updated the question with what I have done

Comment: it seems you are trying with C , i put example with JAVA, then need to give another example

Comment: @AnishKumar do you also have to consider missing data or we are talking about a perfect data set here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there is nothing that does it out of the box. But you have all the tools to build it yourself

#### The C way

You read the lines into a char * (with `cin.getline()`) and then use strtok, and strcpy

#### The getline way

The `getline` function accept a third parameter to specify a delimiter. You can make use of that to split the line through a `istringstream`. Something like :

```
int main() {
    std::string line, temp;
    std::ifstream myfile("file.txt");
    std::getline(myfile, line);
    while (myfile.good()) {
        empdata data;
        std::getline(myfile, line);
        if (myfile.eof()) {
            break;
        }
        std::istringstream istr(line);
        std::getline(istr, temp, '|');
        data.sl = ::strtol(temp.c_str(), NULL, 10);
        std::getline(istr, temp, '|');
        data.empNO = ::strtol(temp.c_str(), NULL, 10);
        istr.getline(data.name, sizeof(data.name), '|');
        istr.getline(data.department, sizeof(data.department), '|');
        istr.getline(data.band, sizeof(data.band), '|');
        istr.getline(data.location, sizeof(data.location), '|');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the C++ version of the previous one

#### The find way

You read the lines into a string (as you currently do) and use `string::find(char sep, size_t pos)` to find next occurence of the separator and copy the data (from string::c_str()) between start of substring and separator to your fields

#### The manual way

You just iterate the string. If the character is a separator, you put a NULL at the end of current field and pass to next field. Else, you just write the character in current position of current field.

#### Which to choose ?

If you are more used to one of them, stick to it.

Following is just my opinion.

The `getline` way will be the simplest to code and to maintain.

The find way is mid level. It is still at a rather high level and avoids the usage of `istringstream`.

The manual way will be really low level, so you should structure it to make it maintainable. For example your could a explicit description of the lines as an array of fields with a maximimum size and current position. And as you have both int and char[] fields it will be tricky. But you can easily configure it the way you want. For example, your code only allow 20 characters for `department` field, whereas `Research and Development` in line 2 is longer. Without special processing, the getline way will leave the `istringstream` in bad state and will not read anything more. And even if you clear the state, you will be badly positionned. So you should first read into a `std::string` and then copy the beginning to the `char *` field.

Here is a working manual implementation :

```
class Field {
public:
    virtual void reset() = 0;
    virtual void add(empdata& data, char c) = 0;
};

class IField: public Field {
private:
    int (empdata::*data_field);
    bool ok;

public:
    IField(int (empdata::*field)): data_field(field) {
        ok = true;
        reset();
    }
    void reset() { ok = true; }
    void add(empdata& data, char c);
};

void IField::add(empdata& data, char c) {
    if (ok) {
        if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) {
            data.*data_field = data.*data_field * 10  + (c - '0');
        }
        else {
            ok = false;
        }
    }
}


class CField: public Field {
private:
    char (empdata::*data_field);
    size_t current_pos;
    size_t size;

public:
    CField(char (empdata::*field), size_t size): data_field(field), size(size) {
        reset();
    }
    void reset() { current_pos = 0; }
    void add(empdata& data, char c);
};

void CField::add(empdata& data, char c) {
    if (current_pos < size) {
        char *ix = &(data.*data_field);
        ix[current_pos ++] = c;
        if (current_pos == size) {
            ix[size -1] = '\0';
            current_pos +=1;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string line, temp;
    std::ifstream myfile("file.txt");
    Field* fields[] = {
        new IField(&empdata::sl),
        new IField(&empdata::empNO),
        new CField(reinterpret_cast<char empdata::*>(&empdata::name), 20),
        new CField(reinterpret_cast<char empdata::*>(&empdata::department), 20),
        new CField(reinterpret_cast<char empdata::*>(&empdata::band), 3),
        new CField(reinterpret_cast<char empdata::*>(&empdata::location), 20),
        NULL
    };
    std::getline(myfile, line);
    while (myfile.good()) {
        Field** f = fields;
        empdata data = {0};
        std::getline(myfile, line);
        if (myfile.eof()) {
            break;
        }
        for (std::string::const_iterator it = line.begin(); it != line.end(); it++) {
            char c;
            c = *it;
            if (c == '|') {
                f += 1;
                if (*f == NULL) {
                    continue;
                }
                (*f)->reset();
            }
            else {
                (*f)->add(data, c);
            }
        }
        // do something with data ...
    }
    for(Field** f = fields; *f != NULL; f++) {
        free(*f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is directly robust, efficient and maintainable : adding a field is easy, and it is tolerant to errors in input file. But it is way loooonger than the other ones, and would need much more tests. So I would not advise to use it without special reasons (necessity to accept multiple separators, optional fields and dynamic order, ...)

Answer (score 8):

I prefer to use the [String Toolkit](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk).  The String Toolkit will take care of converting the numbers as it parses.

Here is how I would solve it.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <strtk.hpp>   // http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk

using namespace std;

// using strings instead of character arrays
class Employee
{
    public:
    int index;
    int employee_number;
    std::string name;
    std::string department;
    std::string band;
    std::string location;
};


std::string filename("empdata.txt");

// assuming the file is text
std::fstream fs;
fs.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in);

if(fs.fail())  return false;   

const char *whitespace    = " \t\r\n\f";

const char *delimiter    = "|";

std::vector<Employee> employee_data;

// process each line in turn
while( std::getline(fs, line ) )
{

// removing leading and trailing whitespace
// can prevent parsing problemsfrom different line endings.

    strtk::remove_leading_trailing(whitespace, line);


    // strtk::parse combines multiple delimeters in these cases

    Employee e;

    if( strtk::parse(line, delimiter, e.index, e.employee_number, e.name, e.department, e.band, e.location) )
    {
         std::cout << "succeed" << std::endl;
     employee_data.push_back( e );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code segment , this will read the file and , give a print , you can read line by line and later you can use that to process as you need .

Data : provided bu you : in file named data.txt.

```
package com.demo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        try {
            File file = new File("data.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String data;

            while ((data = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // data = br.readLine( );
                System.out.println(data);
            }   

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In console  you will get output like this :

```
Sl|EmployeeID|Name|Department|Band|Location
1|327427|Brock Mcneil|Research and Development|U2|Pune
2|310456|Acton Golden|Advertising|P3|Hyderabad
3|305540|Hollee Camacho|Payroll|U3|Bangalore
4|218801|Simone Myers|Public Relations|U3|Pune
5|144051|Eaton Benson|Advertising|P1|Chennai
```

This is a simple idea, you may do what you need.

Comment: Basically my question is how to extract data from a string which has data separated by '|' character and store each data to a separate variable.
I'm doing it in C

Comment: @Forhad: Since the OP has now posted code, it becomes apparent that he's doing C++. So you should probably adapt your answer, or delete it, because a Java answer to a C++ question looks a bit out of place. ;-)

Comment: its time for another answer using c++ @DevSolar

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can change the locale to add an extra character to the separator list of the current locale:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

struct pipe_is_space : std::ctype<char> {
  pipe_is_space() : std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}
  static mask const* get_table()
  {
    static mask rc[table_size];
    rc['|'] = std::ctype_base::space;
    rc['\n'] = std::ctype_base::space;
    return &rc[0];
  }
};

int main() {
  using std::string;
  using std::cin;
  using std::locale;

  cin.imbue(locale(cin.getloc(), new pipe_is_space));

  string word;
  while(cin >> word) {
    std::cout << word << "\n";
  }
}
```